# Testing Stripe with Cypress automatin tool not working

Tags: testing, automation, frontend, stripe-payments, cypress

I'm trying to write a Cypress test that interacts with Stripe checkout on our testing env to demonstrate a user checkout and cancel subscription . Unfortunately I'm hitting a white screen from Stripe after the first click before even typing some data, its looks like something is loading but its state dosent change at all.

The code:

```
describe("Create new subscription and cancel it", () => {
before("Login and reset account", () => {
    cy.loginViaApi("user", "pass", Cypress.env("TESTING_URL"));
    cy.resetAccount("user", "pass", Cypress.env("TESTING_URL"));
});
it("nav", () => {
    cy.visit("/sub-plans");
    cy.get('[data-id="planBtn"]').click({ multiple: true });
});
```

});

[image: This is how it looks]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried comparing the Checkout Session URL that the page was redirected to and the [url](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-url) that was returned by Stripe?

Comment: this is the redirected url : https://checkout.stripe.com/c/pay/cs_test_a1iCCTQ8TcPixjy31I.... and i didnt found the CO session

Comment: what you pasted is definitely isn't a full (or correct) Checkout Session url, it's way too short. If you try to create a Checkout Session and inspect the returned `url`, it's way longer than that. You can try using https://stripe.com/docs?shell=true&api=true&resource=checkout%20sessions&action=create

Comment: It's possible to create an automated test that iilustrates dummy checkout on testing env ?